# Not sure if grunt or bower are installing

Tags: git, gruntjs, npm, bower

So I try install grunt via the terminal using

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

and i get the following errors

```
npm ERR! Darwin 13.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.0.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/grunt
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path:       '/usr/local/bin/grunt' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/grunt'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/grunt' }
```

When i try with

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

it gives me this

```
/usr/local/bin/grunt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.1, glob@3.2.11)
```

Not sure what that means, but I doubt it means it's installed.

I get the same thing with bower.

I've already isntalled git via their GUI .pkg

please help :/

Answer (score 1):

How can you not be sure it is ? Have you tried to run it in the terminal using either `grunt` or `bower` commands ?

Because the last logs seems to have **successfully installed** the *grunt-cli* correctly, with all its dependencies.

If you can't run the command, you should make sure that the `grunt-cli binary` is in your `PATH`. And there is a lot of luck that `/usr/local/bin` was already in it.

Answer (score 0):

`Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Try running `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`. However, I would highly recommend installing [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: I said I did that too in the original posting...
What it returned on the terminal... does that mean it's installed?

Answer (score 0):

The output indicates that it has been installed successfully. The output is telling you the dependencies which it also had to install along with grunt in order for it to work.

Typically, npm will install packages to your user `node_modules bin` directory. You need to make sure this is on your path.

In order to do this you will need to find out your home directory:

To find your home directory run (assuming Linux or macOSX, e.g. a *nix system): 
`echo ~`

This will give you something like (on a mac): `"/Users/jsmith"`

To add to your PATH variable: find your bash file -- this will either be named `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. Or something else if you use another shell; but bash is the most common.

**On Linux**

Your home directory (run `echo ~`) will look something like `/usr/home/local/jsmith`. Open the bash file in a text editor (or in vim using the command line - e.g. `vim ~/.bash_profile`) and add the line

`export PATH=/user/home/local/jsmith/npm/bin:$PATH;`

Save and close the file.

**On MacOSX**

Same as linux above but make sure to note the home directory will be different, e.g.

`export PATH=/Users/jsmith/npm/bin:$PATH;`

You need to reload the bash file for the changes to take effect. You can just open a new terminal window, or in the current window run `. ~/.bash_profile` (or .bashrc, etc. depending on your system and terminal choice) which will reload the bash file in the current terminal.

The available `npm` commands can now be run from any terminal. You can find the names of what is available by looking in the node_modules bin folder: `ls ~/npm/bin`.

If you can't run those listed in the bin folder make sure the permissions are correct on those -- you can see this by running `ls -l ~/npm/bin` (permissions should be correctly set when installed by npm). Just search for `chmod` if this is something you have to look at.

And I'll leave the setup on Windows for someone else to comment on :)